# SQL Self Join not "joining" in PopSQL

Tags: sql, popsql

I'm currently learning SQL and came across an obstacle.
I have been looking around the web and found no case where the table is being "replicated" as is my case.

The case is based on a classical example where we want to have a result where we get the employee name and the next column with the supervisor name.

Desired result:

```
|Employee Name | Supervisor Name|
---------------------------------
|Dave          | NULL           |
|Rick          | Dave           |
|Andy          | Rick           |
```

The current table goes like this (employee):

```
|emp_id | first_name | last_name| super_id |
--------------------------------------------
|100    | Dave       | Star     |  NULL    |
|101    | Rick       | Port     |  100     |
|101    | Andy       | Huds     |  101     |
```

I'm trying to do this with a SELF JOIN in POPSQL (MySQL based) but first I will show how the employee table was created.

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    emp_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name  VARCHAR(40), 
    super_id INT,
);

ALTER TABLE employee
ADD FOREIGN KEY (super_id)
REFERENCES employee(emp_id)
ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

This is the code I'm using to make the query:

```
SELECT m.first_name, s.first_name
FROM employee AS m
INNER JOIN employee AS s
ON m.super_id = s.emp_id;
```

And below the result I'm getting.
Notice how the table has two problems.
First, each row seems to be repeated (David appears in two rows).
Second, the emp_id is not matched to sup_id (as per the ON m.super_id = s.emp_id).

```
|emp_id | first_name |
----------------------
|David  | David      |
|David  | David      |
|Rick   | Rick       |
|Rick   | Rick       |
```

Could somebody help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to get all records (including Dave), you need to use **OUTER JOIN**

```
SELECT m.first_name AS EmployeeName, 
s.first_name AS SupervisorName
FROM employee AS m
LEFT JOIN employee AS s
ON m.super_id = s.emp_id;
```

Comment: Thanks! This code seems to work. I'm now amazed of something. I don't know how to add a follow up correctly. I'm unable to add a code block in this little comment box lol. Why is it that if I do NOT use the SELECT with "AS" the self join does not seem to work?

Comment: the inner join retrieves only the matched rows (ON m.super_id = s.emp_id). in your data, Dave does not have a super_id so it does not match with inner join

Comment: AS keyword is just for alias, you do not have to use it. LEFT JOIN is the magic here.

Comment: I get the usage of the LEFT JOIN. Makes total sense. Thanks. But if I take the code you mentioned and delete the "AS EmployeeName" and "AS SupervisorName" the result changes radically. The result will only show NULL | NULL -- David | David ,etc... Why is this happening?

Comment: AS keywords do not affect the result, they are just for the alias

Comment: I will show what I mean with images.
Hope this gets my point across clearly
With AS
[1]: https://ibb.co/tZqDL1M
Without AS
[2]: https://ibb.co/dJswj6H

Can you see the difference? SQL does not seem to match the ids correctly without the AS

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: This one. I was actually using a simplified version for the example above but it should be essentially the same.
https://ibb.co/9cGck5X

Comment: I believe I can re-post this as a separate question now since we are looking at why does "AS" change the result of the query. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you using mysql? or any other dbms?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT m.first_name, s.first_name
FROM employee AS m
left JOIN employee AS s
ON m.super_id = s.emp_id;
```

Comment: Works exactly as desired. See follow up on mehmetx answer.

Comment: I Didn't use emplyeename or supervisorname as alias Is it returning wrong result?